# Granting remote access to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grant remote access to a mysql database. However I think I am missing a step somewhere.

- Server is a VM - Ubuntu 12.04.5 -  inet addr:134.226.38.147
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Firstly I create the database on the remote server. I then grant wildcard access to all databases and tables for the user brendan. By using `'%'` I should have no problem connecting from my computer in college.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'brendan'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

I then open the port using

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save | tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

From what I read the above should work, however when I try to test the connection from my desktop this is what I get

```
localhost:~ brendan$ mysql -u brendan -h 134.226.38.147 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '134.226.38.147' (61)
localhost:~ brendan$
```

or

```
localhost:~ brendan$ echo X | telnet -e X 134.226.38.147 3306
Telnet escape character is 'X'.
Trying 134.226.38.147...
telnet: connect to address 134.226.38.147: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
localhost:~ brendan$
```

What am I missing?

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

**my.cnf**

I was unsure If I should comment out the `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` which was already there

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

# ---- You added the below line ----------

bind-address            = 134.226.38.147
```

I then restart with

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: can you even ping that host?

Comment: What does the `bind-address` on your `my.cnf` look like?

Comment: Is the MySQL server in a commercial datacenter? If so the MySQL port may be blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @OllieJones It is a shared account (VM) on a college sever, located somewhere on campus (I'm told). It is very possible it might be blocked, do you know of a quick way to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your my.cnf file:

`sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment out the bind-address in your `my.cnf`.

like so: `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Then restart mysql server so that the changes to the my.cnf file will take affect.

`sudo service mysql restart`

or

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

You can read more here at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-allow-remote-mysql-database-connection) or [rtcamp](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/).

Now, a user will be able to connect to the Mysql database server remotely as long as they have proper user credentials.